# SurfaceHolder.Callback. при блокировке экрана surfaceDestroyed не вызывается

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, activity-life-cycle

В `surfaceDestroyed()` у меня происходит передача флага,чтобы остановить игру и попытка остановить поток.

Если попытаться кнопкой <kbd>Домой</kbd> свернуть, `surfaceDestroyed()` вызывается и при возвращении в программу вызывается `surfaceCreated()`. Если заблокировать экран кнопкой питания, то `surfaceDestroyed()` не вызывается, т.е. я не могу остановить поток...

И второй вопрос: если нажать кнопку назад вызывается метод 
    `protected void onDestroy(){
        Log.d(TAG,"Destroying...");
        super.onDestroy();
    }`

Как сделать так , чтобы кнопка назад не убивала приложение ? И как остановить поток , если я блокирую экран кнопкой питания?

Ну и материал для размышления :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495842/how-surfaceholder-callbacks-are-related-to-activity-lifecycle

http://ru.androids.help/q22562